# Doctrine 2 inheritance in a Symfony 2 project without discriminating column?

Tags: database, inheritance, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm creating a bundle for Symfony 2 that has two user types. Only one user type will be used (the class is specified in the services configuration). I have defined two `User` classes that inherit from a common base class (using single table inheritance). However, the discriminator column seems like a waste of space to me. Is there a way to inherit from the base class without using STI?

If I leave out the `InheritanceType`annotation, the Symfony console command `doctrine:update:schema` tries to create the user table twice and throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inheritance model depends on the discriminator column to work.  You can't leave it out.

It's not a waste of space.  You trade a little space for more reliable and performant ORM.